# server linux - Unable to initialize OpenSSL library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, pascal, lazarus

I have a problem with running my application on vps server. I have there Ubuntu. On my personal computer I install ubuntu too. On my computer my application runs and work but on server I got this:

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $080C9936 :
Exception : Unable to initialize OpenSSL library, please check your OpenSSL installation
$080C9936  TLSSLSESSION__CREATESSLCONTEXT,  line 503 of ./lnet/lnetssl.pp
$080C9B96  TLSSLSESSION__CREATE,  line 547 of ./lnet/lnetssl.pp
$0804866B  TSERWER__CREATE,  line 41 of serwer.lpr
$08048BC7  main,  line 123 of serwer.lpr
```

probably on linux openssl is default installed but I do this:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Everything install ok and I do:

```
apt-cache search libssl | grep SSL
```

I didnt get any info... Its only error 'configure directory/file dosent exist'

Probably I should configure this openssl but I dont know how. Can you help me?

Comment: what are you using? vps service? ubuntu version? did you try `apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean`? after that try `sudo apt-get update` & try `sudo apt-get purge openssl` and reinstall `sudo apt-get install openssl` , but please give more detail
`

Comment: Yes, I use this: https://tiktalik.com
ok thx Ill try

Comment: Can You look at this?

`root@myserver:# apt -get autoremove
E: Command line option 'g' [from -get] is not known.
root@myserver:# sudo apt -cache seach libss | grep ssl
E: Opening configuration file ache - ifstream::ifstream (2: No such file or directory)
root@myserver:# sudo apt -get autoremove
E: Command line option 'g' [from -get] is not known.
root@myserver:# apt -cache search libssl | grep ssl
E: Opening configuration file ache - ifstream::ifstream (2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: if I see correctly, you are on `sudo` (the `#` sign). and you have a space between the dasd `-` and the `apt`...not suppose to be there!!! put them together so: `apt-get`. same with `-cache`...should be without spaces, so `apt-cache`...I suggest reading a little about termianl commansd `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal` & `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto?action=show&redirect=AptGetHowto`

Comment: Thank You, I made mistake but still have this same problem :(On my local ubuntu everything is ok but on vps service I still get  like in first post.
After: sudo apt-cache search libssl | grep ssl

Comment: `
 libssl-dev - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
libssl-doc - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
libssl1.0.0 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
libssl1.0.0-dbg - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - debug information
`

Comment: libssl-ocaml - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL (runtime)
libssl-ocaml-dev - OCaml bindings for OpenSSL
libssl0.9.8 - SSL shared libraries
libssl0.9.8-dbg - Symbol tables for libssl and libcrypto
libsslcommon2 - enterprise messaging system - common SSL libraries
libsslcommon2-dev - enterprise messaging system - common SSL development files

Answer (score 0):

I compile application on server side and everything is OK!! :)

Thank for helping :)